# Is it possible to give tool tip every QComboBox item in QtDesigner?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

Is it possible to give tool tip every QComboBox item in QtDesigner? Instead of using [set item data](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#setItemData)?

Comment: no, it is not possible, you have to do it with code.